# Group by ID and Outcome and take the earliest earliest Dates of specific outcomes and assign numbers (i.e outcome1, outcome2)

Tags: r, group-by, data-manipulation

Apologies if I am not explaining this clearly.
But I have the following dataset:

```
mydata = data.frame (Id =c (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
Date = c("2001-01-31", "2001-02-13","2001-05-31",
"2001-06-02","2018-01-31","2018-03-31","2018-07-31",
"2019-04-04","2014-01-31","2014-02-02","2014-04-31",
"2014-05-18"),Outcome = c("CR","CR","Relapse","Relapse",
"CR","CR","CR","Relapse","CR", "CR","Relapse","CR"))
```

Which outputs the below. As you can see each patient is in certain phases at different times and I would like to capture the earliest dates of when each new phase starts per patient. I would like then to rename these phases to CR1, Relapse1, CR2, Relapse2 and so forth.

```
Id     Date        Outcome
1   2001-01-31  CR      
1   2001-02-13  CR      
1   2001-05-31  Relapse     
1   2001-06-02  Relapse     
1   2018-01-31  CR      
1   2018-03-31  CR      
1   2018-07-31  CR      
1   2019-04-04  Relapse     
2   2014-01-31  CR      
2   2014-02-02  CR
2   2014-04-31  Relapse     
2   2014-05-18  CR
```

This is the output I am trying to achieve:

```
Id     CR1       Relapse1      CR2       Relapse2
1   2001-01-31  2001-05-31  2018-01-31  2019-04-04
2   2014-01-31  2014-04-31  2014-05-18  NA
```

I am not quite sure where to begin with this question and would appreciate any help! Thank you guys!

Comment: Do you you mean the earliest of each ID year outcome combination? or the earliest and latest of each ID outcome?

Comment: Is the order of the end result variables important? I.e.. Does it matter if you get CR1, CR2, Relapese1, Relapse2?

Comment: @Macosso The earliest date of each ID and outcome combination Before they switch to another outcome.

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez yes the first CR before they hit relapse should be labelled as CR1 and then after should be relapse1. If they were to achieve CR again after being in relapse once it should be CR2 and so forth

Comment: Follow up question on this, is it at all possible to only start the counting after the first CR has been seen? So if an id has Relapse before CR that would be ignored and then first relapse after the first CR would be considered as Relapse 1? Thank you!! –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tidyverse` you can try the following.

(If needed, first `arrange` by `Date` so it is in chronological order.)

Create a grouping value depending on change in the `Outcome` column (from remission to relapse and vice versa). I used `rleid` from `data.table` for convenience and created a temporary column, `Grp`. For example:

```
      Id Date       Outcome   Grp
   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>   <int>
 1     1 2001-01-31 CR          1
 2     1 2001-02-13 CR          1
 3     1 2001-05-31 Relapse     2
 4     1 2001-06-02 Relapse     2
 5     1 2018-01-31 CR          3
 6     1 2018-03-31 CR          3
 7     1 2018-07-31 CR          3
 8     1 2019-04-04 Relapse     4
 9     2 2014-01-31 CR          1
10     2 2014-02-02 CR          1
11     2 2014-04-31 Relapse     2
12     2 2014-05-18 CR          3
```

You can see, within each `Id`, that when the `Outcome` changes, the `Grp` increases. That way, subsequent dates with the same `Outcome` will be included in the same `Grp`.

The `.add` argument allows us to add `Grp` to the prior grouping, which was just `Id`. So, grouping now by both `Grp` and `Id`, you can then `slice` the first row. `slice(1)` or `slice(n = 1)` will keep 1 row within the group. In this case, we have grouped by both `Id` and `Grp`, so only 1 row will be kept for a given `Grp` and `Id` combination.

Finally, you can add a row number that will allow for the wide output described (a consecutive sequence of numbers for CR and Relapse: 1, 2, 3, 4...). In this case, we `group_by` both `Id` and `Outcome`, and consecutively number the dates for this combination. `pivot_wider` will put the data into wide format if desired.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Grp = rleid(Outcome)) %>%
  group_by(Grp, .add = T) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  group_by(Id, Outcome) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Id, names_from = c(Outcome, n), values_from = Date)
```

**Output**

```
     Id CR_1       Relapse_1  CR_2       Relapse_2 
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1     1 2001-01-31 2001-05-31 2018-01-31 2019-04-04
2     2 2014-01-31 2014-04-31 2014-05-18 NA
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried that but keep getting the following error:                                         
```                                                                                                                                           
Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `Grp`.
x could not find function "rleid"
ℹ Input `Grp` is `rleid(Outcome)`                                                                                                           ```

Comment: @Ben, ahh you were faster than me by 3 minutes :( Anyway I only could manage to solve it using subsets and shitf() function. Can you explain what does this line: `group_by(Grp = rleid(Outcome), .add = T) %>%` do? As well as `slice(1)` .

Comment: @Ben That worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: @Ben Totally helpful!

Comment: Edited so that with `rleid` numbering restarts with change in `Id`.

Comment: @Ben Follow up question on this if you dont mind. Is it at all possible to only start the counting after the first CR has been seen? So if an id has Relapse before CR that would be ignored and then first relapse after the first CR would be considered as Relapse 1? Thank you!!

Comment: @TK I answered your other question - hope this helps!