# Group by ID and Outcome and take the earliest earliest Dates and assign numbers (i.e outcome1, outcome2) AFTER specific outcome has occurred

Tags: r, group-by, data-manipulation

Apologies I am not sure this warrants another question. But am basing this off of another questions ([Group by ID and Outcome and take the earliest earliest Dates of specific outcomes and assign numbers (i.e outcome1, outcome2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70086944/group-by-id-and-outcome-and-take-the-earliest-earliest-dates-of-specific-outcome)).

```
mydata = data.frame (Id =c (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
Date = c("2001-01-31", "2001-02-13","2001-05-31",
"2001-06-02","2018-01-31","2018-03-31","2018-07-31",
"2019-04-04","2014-01-31","2014-02-02","2014-04-31",
"2014-05-18"),Outcome = c("Relapse","CR","Relapse","Relapse",
"CR","CR","CR","Relapse","CR", "CR","Relapse","CR"))
```

Which outputs the below.

```
Id     Date        Outcome
1   2001-01-31  Relapse      
1   2001-02-13  CR      
1   2001-05-31  Relapse     
1   2001-06-02  Relapse     
1   2018-01-31  CR      
1   2018-03-31  CR      
1   2018-07-31  CR      
1   2019-04-04  Relapse     
2   2014-01-31  CR      
2   2014-02-02  CR
2   2014-04-31  Relapse     
2   2014-05-18  CR
```

As you can see each patient is in certain phases at different times and I would like to capture the earliest dates of when each new phase starts per patient. I would like then to rename these phases to CR1, Relapse1, CR2, Relapse2 and so forth. **But I would only like to start naming AFTER patient achieves their first CR1. So if a patient has a relapse before CR, those would be ignored.**

Im hoping to get an output like this:

```
Id     CR1       Relapse1      CR2       Relapse2
1   2001-02-13  2001-05-31  2018-01-31  2019-04-04
2   2014-01-31  2014-04-31  2014-05-18  NA
```

As you see patient 1 had a relapse at 2001-01-31, but was ignored because it occured before the first CR1.

The following code was so helpful to the previous question, but was wondering if I can modify it so that it will start the counting after the first CR? Thank you!!

```
mydata %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Grp = rleid(Outcome)) %>%
  group_by(Grp, .add = T) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  group_by(Id, Outcome) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Id, names_from = c(Outcome, n), values_from = Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
mydata <- setDT(mydata)

# identify consecutive same Outcome for each Id
mydata[, flag:=rleid(Id, Outcome)]

# collapse identified consecutive values (keep min date)
tmp <- mydata[, by="flag,Id,Outcome", .(Date=min(Date))]

# mark relapse if first
tmp <- tmp[, by=Id,
  flag := (Outcome[1]=="Relapse") & (seq_len(.N)==1)
]

# remove marked relapse
tmp <- tmp[(!flag)]

# Outcome numbering
tmp[, by="Id,Outcome", n:=seq_len(.N)]

# cast (widen)
dcast(tmp, Id~paste0(Outcome, n), value.var = "Date")
```

Got

```
   Id        CR1        CR2   Relapse1   Relapse2
1:  1 2001-02-13 2018-01-31 2001-05-31 2019-04-04
2:  2 2014-01-31 2014-05-18 2014-04-31       <NA>
```

using %>% notation

```
mydata[, flag:=rleid(Id,Outcome)] %>%
  .[, by="flag,Id,Outcome", .( Date=min(Date) )] %>%
  .[, by="Id", flag := (Outcome[1]=="Relapse") & (seq_len(.N)==1)] %>%
  .[(!flag)] %>%
  .[, by="Id,Outcome", n := seq_len(.N)] %>%
  dcast(., Id ~ paste0(Outcome, n), value.var = "Date")
```

Answer (score 0):

That is my approach :

```
library(data.table)

my_df <- data.frame (Id =c (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 Date = c("2001-01-31", "2001-02-13","2001-05-31",
                          "2001-06-02","2018-01-31","2018-03-31","2018-07-31",
                          "2019-04-04","2014-01-31","2014-02-02","2014-04-31",
                          "2014-05-18"),
                 Outcome = c("Relapse","Relapse","Relapse","Relapse",
                             "CR","CR","CR","Relapse","CR", "CR","Relapse","CR"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_df <- my_df %>% group_by(Id) %>% arrange(Id, Date)

my_df <- my_df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Value = seq_along(Outcome)) %>%
  mutate(first_v = Outcome == "CR" & !duplicated(Outcome == "CR")) %>%
  mutate(first_a = first_v == "FALSE" & Value > Value[Outcome == "CR" & !duplicated(Outcome == "CR")] | Outcome == "CR") %>%
  filter(first_a == "TRUE")

my_df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(Grp = rleid(Outcome)) %>%
  group_by(Grp, .add = T) %>%
  group_by(Id, Outcome) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Id, names_from = c(Outcome, n), values_from = Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding:

```
filter(Date >= first(Date[Outcome == "CR"]))
```

to `filter` out rows before the first "CR". This assumes your `Date` is sorted/arranged first.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

mydata %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  filter(Date >= first(Date[Outcome == "CR"])) %>%
  mutate(Grp = rleid(Outcome)) %>%
  group_by(Grp, .add = T) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  group_by(Id, Outcome) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Id, names_from = c(Outcome, n), values_from = Date)
```

**Output**

```
     Id CR_1       Relapse_1  CR_2       Relapse_2 
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1     1 2001-02-13 2001-05-31 2018-01-31 2019-04-04
2     2 2014-01-31 2014-04-31 2014-05-18 NA
```